# Best approach for c# web service with concurrent users

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to C# but have experience with C++.

I'm looking to write a web service, that I can call from a website to pull hotel rates similar to rate comparison websites.  My question is; what is the best method to be able to deal with the concurrent loads and allow the data requests to run in the background whilst updating the user interface.

Basically I've all the code ready and to pull the XML data from the likes of Booking.com, on a single per user basis.

But want to change this way of working, to allow me to send off requests to say 10 suppliers at once, and then in the background the web service works to get the rates.

The front end, will then refresh to get the latest data.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: So your plan is to scan and scrape other sites like booking.com in real-time every time a user requests rates?

Comment: asynchronous is the word.

Comment: No, Roy I will be using a proper XML connect with the appropriate requests via XML.  On obtaining the rate information I was planning on storing it in a database, ready to be displayed to the client.

Comment: Does anyone have any good examples they can share ?